# Emacs hl-line: change color locally

Tags: emacs, line, text-cursor

I normally let hl-line take a slightly darker shade of current background.  This works nice in editing buffers.  However, in some buffers, such as Org agenda and the Gnus group buffer, I would like to use a more spiffy color (in place of the cursor).

To be specific I would like to change the color of hl-line in the gnus-hl-line *without* affecting the color of hl-line in other buffers.

```
(add-hook 'gnus-summary-mode-hook 'gnus-hl-line)
(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'gnus-hl-line)

(defun gnus-hl-line ()
  (hl-line-mode 1)
  (set (make-local-variable 'line-move-visual) nil)
  (setq cursor-type nil))
```

Thanks,

Final solution using Phil's suggestion.  It uses a neutral hl line most of the time, but sometimes a bold hl-line is appreciable, e.g. in Gnus and Org agenda

```
;; From emacs-wiki:
(defun shade-color (intensity)
  "print the #rgb color of the background, dimmed according to intensity"
  (interactive "nIntensity of the shade : ")
  (apply 'format "#%02x%02x%02x"
         (mapcar (lambda (x)
                   (if (> (lsh x -8) intensity)
                       (- (lsh x -8) intensity)
                     0))
                 (color-values (cdr (assoc 'background-color (frame-parameters)))))))

;; Default hl
(global-hl-line-mode t)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'global-hl-line-mode)
(set-face-background hl-line-face (shade-color 08))  

(defface hl-line-highlight-face
  '((t :inherit highlight))
  "Face for highlighting the current line with `hl-line-fancy-highlight'."
  :group 'hl-line)

(defun hl-line-fancy-highlight ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'hl-line-face) 'hl-line-highlight-face)
  ;;    (set (make-local-variable 'line-move-visual) nil)
  ;;    (set (make-local-variable 'cursor-type) nil)
  (setq global-hl-line-mode nil)
  (hl-line-mode))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'hl-line-fancy-highlight)
(add-hook 'gnus-summary-mode-hook 'hl-line-fancy-highlight)
(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'hl-line-fancy-highlight)
```

Comment: Could you please explain where in the code one can set the intensity *and* the colour for the org-agenda, gnus-summary and gnus-group respectively? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hl-line-face` is a variable containing the face to use for `hl-line-mode`, so we can make that variable buffer-local in these modes, and assign it a new custom face.

You can create a new face like this:

```el
(defface gnus-hl-line
  '((t :inherit hl-line))
  "Face for highlighting the current line with `gnus-hl-line'."
  :group 'hl-line)
```

and customize it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `gnus-hl-line` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Then add this in your `gnus-hl-line` function (before calling `hl-line-mode` would seem most sensible).

```el
(set (make-local-variable 'hl-line-face) 'gnus-hl-line)
```